# Exception: Access Denied when using FileStream

Tags: c#, exception, administrator

The following line is throwing an exception. I have no idea why.

```
using (var output = new FileStream(sftpFile.Name, FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite))
```

Exception is:

```
Error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\roberth\
Programming_Projects\Common\UI\bin\Debug' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, 
Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions 
options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, 
Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at CWD.Networking.DownloadFromSftp(String hostname, String user, String passw
ord, Int32 port, String localPath, String remotePath, String filename) in c:\Use
rs\roberth\Programming_Projects\Common\Common\Common.cs:line 566
```

Line 566 is the using statement above.

Can anyone shed some light as to why I may be triggering an error? I have full permissions to the directory, no compilation issues, I can create new files and folders manually in that directory as well.

--Edit--

I tried running VS as administrator as suggested with no resolution.

Comment: If you are running with UAC (User Account Control), ensure Visual Studio is launched as an administrator.

Comment: @Arran we are, let me try as admin

Comment: Can you post `sftpFile.Name`? (The actual value, and not what you expect it to be) Does a file(or directory) with that name already exist? For example if appending the filename to the path failed, and thus pointed to the parent directory you'd get some error.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I am downloading from the sftp server, the files do not exist on the local drive. If the file did exist locally I would expect it to throw a different exception. In order to source the file I am running `foreach(var sftpFile in client.ListDirectory("."))` which will properly display the name of the file if I output to console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `UnauthorizedAccessException` error message tells you what file it is you're trying to open:

```
C:\Users\roberth\Programming_Projects\Common\UI\bin\Debug
```

This looks like a directory name: you can't open a directory as a file.

You've presumably forgotten to append a filename:

```
string filename = Path.Combine(sftpFile.Name, "SomeFile.dat");
using (var output = new FileStream(filename,...)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: interesting - works if I specify the name manually, but if I try to pass it the filename on the sftp server it fails. Guess I have some more work to do :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use something similar to the following:

```
private bool EnviarArchivoSFTP(string PuertoSFTP, string UrlFTP, string CarpetaFTP, string UsuarioFTP, string PasswordFTP, string FicheroFTP, string nombreArchivo)
{
    bool archivoEnviado = false;

    using (var client = new SftpClient(UrlFTP, int.Parse(PuertoSFTP), UsuarioFTP, PasswordFTP))
    {
        client.ConnectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        client.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        client.Connect();
        client.ChangeDirectory(CarpetaFTP);

        string dataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
        string appFile = Path.Combine(dataPath, FicheroFTP, nombreArchivo);//Se brindan permisos full sobre la carpeta

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(appFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024; // bypass Payload error large files
            client.UploadFile(fileStream, Path.GetFileName(nombreArchivo));
            archivoEnviado = true;
        }
    }
    return archivoEnviado;
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped me solve my problem. In my case, I explicitly used Read permissions to the file: 
using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(reportPathAndName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))